# Compute the Gauss curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

> Map \begin{align*}
> \phi:\qquad S^2\quad &\longrightarrow\quad\mathbb{R}^4\\
>  (x, y, z)\quad &\longmapsto\quad (\frac{x^2-y^2}{2}, xy, yz, zx)
> \end{align*}
>    is an immersion. Take the standard metric on $ \mathbb{R}^4 $: $ \operatorname{d}s^2=\operatorname{d}x_1^2+\operatorname{d}x_2^2+\operatorname{d}x_3^2+\operatorname{d}x_4^2 $ then $ \phi $ induces a Riemannian metric on $ S^2 $
>    \begin{align*}
>  \phi^*\operatorname{d}s^2&=\operatorname{d}\phi_1^2+\operatorname{d}\phi_2^2+\operatorname{d}\phi_3^2+\operatorname{d}\phi_4^2\\
>  &=(x\operatorname{d}x-y\operatorname{d}y)^2+(y\operatorname{d}x+x\operatorname{d}y)^2\\
>  &\quad +(z\operatorname{d}y+y\operatorname{d}z)^2+(z\operatorname{d}x+x\operatorname{d}z)^2\\
>  &=\operatorname{d}x^2+\operatorname{d}y^2+(x^2+y^2-2z^2)\operatorname{d}z^2.
>  \end{align*}

How to compute the Gauss curvature of $ S^2 $ regarding the metric induced by $ 
\phi $?

I have tried to use the stereographic projection:
\begin{align*}
X_1:\qquad\mathbb R^2\quad &\longrightarrow\quad S^2-\{ (1, 0, 0) \} \\
 (u, v)\quad&\longmapsto\quad\frac{1}{1+u^2+v^2}(u^2+v^2-1, 2u, 2v) 
\end{align*}
and compute the first and the second fundamental forms to gain the Gauss curvature.

But, the huge amount of computations made me quit doing this. I want to know whether there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is indeed to use a parametrisation of $S^2$. Instead of using the stereographic projection, I think the usual
$$
  \begin{align*}
    x &= \cos u \sin v \\
    y &= \sin u \sin v \\
    z &= \cos v,
  \end{align*}
  \qquad \qquad \text{$u \in (0,2\pi)$, $v \in (0,\pi)$,}
$$
will make things a bit easier. The map $\phi$ becomes
$$
 \phi(u,v) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos (2 u) \sin ^2v,\sin (2 u) \sin ^2v,
                   \sin u \sin (2 v),\cos u \sin (2 v)\right).
$$
Then the metric becomes $\phi_u \cdot \phi_u = \sin^2 v$, $\phi_u \cdot \phi_v=0$ and $\phi_v\cdot\phi_v = \tfrac{1}{8}(5+3\cos (4v))$. The calculations will not go superswift, but will this be more manageable for you?

Comment: @Philip Did you manage to calculate the Gaussian curvature from the metric?